# Indexes on an indexed family

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure if this is actually a math question but here I go:

In a proof, given a vectorial space and a set of vectors $\{v_j|j\in J\}$, then it goes saying that $v_{j_1},...v_{j_k}$ satisfies $k<=n$.

What does it mean that last part, in terms of the number of vectors in the given set?

J is supposed to be infinite in the beginning (the proof wants to prove that J is actually finite), and it's the proof of the corollary that states that all bases of a vector space (finite dimension) have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the context probably the vectorial space was of dimension $n$ and the list 
$v_{j_{1}},...,v_{j_{k}}$ makes reference to a set of $k$ vectors where $n$ is greater or equal than $n$, those index are just for enumerating the elements of $J$ and therefore enumerating the list of vectors.

If you could give a reference about the theorem, it could be easier, but at least I gave you an idea.